# Allocating memory for structure types in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Im having an issue in my program where I define a structure type but not a structure variable in a header as such.

```
typedef struct 
{     
    int a;     
    int b;   
    int c;
    Token d;
} Foo;
```

I then want to use this struct `foo` later on in a .c file that does infix to postfix

```
#include "header"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int infix2postfix(char *infix, Arr arr) 
{
    struct Foo foo;
    char szToken[MAX_TOKEN];
    Stack stack = newStack();
    infix = getToken(infix, szToken, MAX_TOKEN); //provides next token to be scanned by function.

    ... //push pop using switch case didn't post code for simplicity.
    case...
    push(stack, *foo.a);

     ...
    case...
    pop(stack);

    ...

    goOut(arr, *foo.d); //goOut(function that populates and "arr" Array from printing.

}
```

So when I compile here I get

```
error: storage size of ‘foo’ isn’t known struct Foo foo;
```

I have tried `struct Foo *foo = malloc(sizeof foo);` to allocate memory but it messes up my `push(stack, *foo.a);` and `goOut(arr, *foo.d);` How do I go about fixing this? Do I have to allocate memory in the `infix2postfix` function first then declare a structure variable?

Comment: You have typedef it to `Foo`. So it need to be `Foo foo;`. That is, no `struct`.

Comment: yep typedef it to Foo

Comment: So when trying to allocate memory it should be `Foo *foo = malloc(sizeof foo);`? @Alan Au

Comment: No. Should be: `Foo *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);` or `Foo *foo = malloc(sizeof Foo);`. I prefer the former as it requires less maintanence if the type changes.

Comment: So I did this and now my `push(stack,*foo.a); `and `goOut(arr, *foo.d); `functions are not working :( Messed up my pointers.

Comment: Hm, I don't see how it could have messed it up since you never had it working in the first place. You can't say it was working before if it wasn't compiling! You obviously have problems elsewhere. Post a new question with the details if you really can't work it out.

Comment: Yeah haha. My issue was that even though I declared the struct variable in the function infix2postfix(); I can't seem to figure out how to allocate memory for it without messing up the rest of my code :(. Im afraid to post it because it might be completely wrong too lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a type `Foo` which is a tagless `struct` type.  You could have a separate `struct Foo { int anonymous; char name[MAX_NAME]; };` which is wholly unrelated to the type `Foo`.  (It would be very confusing for humans, but the compiler would have no problem.)

In your function, you should write:

```
int infix2postfix(char *infix, Arr arr) 
{
    Foo foo;
```

Comment: I had this in my function since I needed a foo variable, but it conflicts with the second argument in both push(); and goOut();. Compiler spits 'invalid uinary *(have int) for push and 'expected Foo but argument is type char for goOut();

Comment: You would need to write just `foo.a`, for example.  The variable `foo` is a structure, and one of its elements is an `int` identified by `foo.a`, and you can' tally the indirection operator `*` to a plain `int`.  If you had an appropriately initialized pointer, `Foo *bar = …;`, you could write `(*bar).a`, or more naturally, `bar->a`.

Comment: It might be that my code is just bad. I tried this aswell and in both `push(stack,foo.a);` and `goOut(out, foo.d);` with the `Foo foo;` declaration and I get `expected 'Foo' as argument 2 but argument is of type int` and `*char` respectively. So somewhere I managed to mess up the syntax of the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

you have already defined Foo as a typedef struct, so you do not use struct Foo again to declare foo, just use
Foo foo; to declare not struct Foo foo;

Comment: Yeah I did this put now my `push(stack, *foo.a);` and `goOut(arr, *foo.d); `have messed up pointers. since *element isnt a structre :(.

Comment: either declare foo as a pointer to Foo.
Foo *foo;

then in push(stack, foo->a)

or declare foo as a struct
Foo foo;
then
push(stack, foo.a)